# Ruby: install gem if user does not have it installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, terminal

I have a ruby script that I want to send to a couple of coworkers.  Instead of telling them to install a few required gems, is there a safe way to have ruby install them if not found?

For example, a user doesn't have the yui-compressor gem.  Instead of the terminal displaying an error when they run `ruby example.rb` it would automatically run `gem install -r yui-compressor` for them.  Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a tool like bundler: http://gembundler.com/